# How to install Nodejs v13.0.1 in alpine:3.8?

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am writing a Dockerfile to dockerize a php + nodejs app. so I start from php:7.2.13-fpm-alpine image which is based on alpine:3.8.
As study I found that I can add latest alpine repositoriy by command

```
apk add  --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/ nodejs
```

However, with this command, I only got nodejs v10.16.3 while I want a latest one(v13.0.1)
Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 13):

Alpine nodejs has two repositories for one LTS and one for the current version.

[Nodejs LTS:](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/nodejs)

> Package   nodejs
>
> Version   12.13.0-r1
>
> Description   JavaScript runtime built on V8 engine - **LTS version**
>
> Project    https://nodejs.org/

[nodejs-current:](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/nodejs-current)

> Package   nodejs-current
>
> Version   13.0.1-r0
>
> Description   JavaScript runtime built on V8 engine - **current stable
> version**
>
> Project   https://nodejs.org/

If you need current version then you have use nodejs-current

```
FROM  alpine:3.8
ENV ALPINE_MIRROR "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine"
RUN echo "${ALPINE_MIRROR}/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs-current  --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community"
RUN node --version
```

Comment: For safety, you should also back up the existing file `/etc/apk/repositories`, and restore it when done.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the follwoing:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache wget

RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.0.1/node-v13.0.1-linux-x64.tar.xz && tar -xf node-v13.0.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

then you will has it in working directory in `node-v13.0.1-linux-x64` folder

Comment: This won't work on other platforms (such as M1 macs) because you're specifying a binary for an explicit platform (x64).