# Error installing nodejs version 12 on alpine linux

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am using the following Dockerfile to install alpine linux as follows
and referred the following stack overflow answer :- [How to install Nodejs v13.0.1 in alpine:3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58725215/how-to-install-nodejs-v13-0-1-in-alpine3-8)

```
FROM alpine:3.9

ENV ALPINE_MIRROR "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine"
RUN echo "${ALPINE_MIRROR}/v3.10/community/" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk add glibc nodejs-current --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/"
RUN node --version
```

Node version results an error

```
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_gettimeofday: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_udp_connect: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_thread_create_ex: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/node: uv_udp_getpeername: symbol not found
The command '/bin/sh -c node --version' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

How to fix this and install node 12.4.0-r0?

Comment: Why don't you use the "node:12-alpine" image?

Comment: Docker will run other services as well and were not supposed to

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want to use alpine:3.9 because other images will also use it?
Why? To save storage space?

Comment: Question is about installing a node version for a docker image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not install `nodejs-current`, as this package is helpful to install ****current version of nodejs*** from edge repository where `nodejs` version does not exist.

In your case, **[nodejs 12.x package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.11)**  already exists so You should install `nodejs` if you want to install an older version instead of `nodejs-current`.

```
FROM alpine:3.9
ENV ALPINE_MIRROR "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine"
RUN echo "${ALPINE_MIRROR}/v3.11/main/" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add nodejs --repository="http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/"
RUN node --version
```

output

```
Removing intermediate container a201832610e0
 ---> b0919df78aef
Step 5/5 : RUN node --version
 ---> Running in cd7950f9303b
v12.15.0
Removing intermediate container cd7950f9303b
 ---> ce54af976f81
Successfully built ce54af976f81
```

Answer (score 3):

alpine:3.12 now uses node v12.22.1

FROM alpine:3.12

RUN node --version

Answer (score 0):

alpine:3.12 now uses node 12.22.10 version

You can check the latest node version based on the alpine version in this [**link**](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.12&repo=main&arch=x86#)

Answer (score 0):

[@Adiii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3288890/adiii)['s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920546/9096986) is almost correct, but the [version number](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.12&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) has to be specified. Otherwise, the latest version would be installed if you are using a newer image. You also don't need the `--repository` option, since you already have it added to your repositories. This way, you can also add packages from other repositories at the same time. And finally, if you need `npm`, you should add it separately.

```
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --update nodejs=12.22.12-r0 npm=12.22.12-r0 other-package
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your Docker file.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/ nodejs=12.22.12-r0 npm=12.22.12-r0
```

You need to pickup the correct repository for the node version you are trying to install.
You can find the correct repository, branch etc from here - https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages